# anaconda not found after update

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried to update anaconda (possibly for the first time after upgrading for OS X El Capitan, not sure), and suddenly it no longer works.

First I updated conda:

```
$ conda update conda
> Fetching package metadata: ....
> # All requested packages already installed.
> # packages in environment at /Users/eddievaisman/anaconda:
> # conda                     3.18.5                   py27_0   ip-192-168-
```

Then I tried to update anaconda:

```
$ conda update anaconda
> Fetching package metadata: ....
> Solving package specifications:
> ................................................................................................................................................
> Package plan for installation in environment
> /Users/eddievaisman/anaconda:
> 
> [a bunch of packages download/installed/updated including
> cytoolz-0.7.4]
> 
> Proceed ([y]/n)? y
> 
> Fetching packages ...
[fetches a bunch of packages]
> Linking packages ...
> An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the     
> |  10% following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:
> 
>     https://github.com/conda/conda/issues
> 
> Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.
> 
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/bin/conda", line 5, in <module    >
>     sys.exit(main())   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py",
> line 195, in main
>     args_func(args, p)   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py",
> line 202, in args_func
>     args.func(args, p)   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py",
> line 48, in execute
>     install.install(args, parser, 'update')   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py",
> line 423, in install
>     plan.execute_actions(actions, index, verbose=not args.quiet)   File
> "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/plan.py",
> line 537, in execute_actions
>     inst.execute_instructions(plan, index, verbose)   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/instructions.py",
> line 148, in execute_instructions
>     cmd(state, arg)   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/instructions.py",
> line 91, in LINK_CMD
>     link(state['prefix'], arg, index=state['index'])   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/instructions.py",
> line 87, in link
>     install.link(pkgs_dir, prefix, dist, lt, index=index)   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/install.py",
> line 613, in link
>     os.makedirs(dst_dir)   File "/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in
> makedirs
>     mkdir(name, mode) OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cytoolz/curried'
```

and now suddenly...

```
$ conda update anaconda
Error: package 'anaconda' is not installed in /Users/eddievaisman/anaconda
```

adnd python doesn't recognize my anaconda packages

```
$ python -c "import pandas"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

My conda info:

```
$ conda info
Current conda install:

             platform : osx-64
        conda version : 3.18.5
  conda-build version : 1.3.3
       python version : 2.7.10.final.0
     requests version : 2.8.1
     root environment : /Users/eddievaisman/anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : /Users/eddievaisman/anaconda
     envs directories : /Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/envs
        package cache : /Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/pkgs
         channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False
```

Why is anaconda no longer recognized? How to fix it?

My path is:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Users/eddievaisman/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I opened an issue: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1832

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER ~/anaconda` followed by `conda install anaconda`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Tried it, didn't work. I own the folder `drwxr-xr-x   25 eddievaisman  staff       850 Nov 17 16:26 anaconda` but get the same error `Error: package 'anaconda' is not installed in /Users/eddievaisman/anaconda`

Comment: Yes, you owned the anaconda folder before as well. But some of the subfolders apparently belong(ed?) to root. Does `conda install anaconda` give you `Error: package 'anaconda' is not installed `? That would be very strange.

Comment: Correct, and I agree it's very strange :) I ended up deleting anaconda and re-installing, which "solved" the problem.